# Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender Problem

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I sent a reply to an email and this is what I got in return, can you translate it for me?
and what should I do?
Mail Delivery System MAILER-DAEMON@mx3.imadiff.net sent :

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.For further assistance, please send mail to If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your own text from the attached returned message.
The mail system
europeanchampion@pfls.fr: host barracuda03.imadiff.net[194.69.195.26] said:

554 rejecting banned content (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; mx3.imadiff.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 6B26E1A50420
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; vermontjf@gmail.com
Arrival-Date: Sun,  4 Apr 2021 10:45:16 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; europeanchampion@pfls.fr
Original-Recipient: rfc822;europeanchampion@pfls.fr
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; barracuda03.imadiff.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 rejecting banned content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty clear in the response you received. The message transfer agent, who's Internet address is mx3.imadiff.net flagged your email as having content that it determined was contraband for their system. You need to look at what you sent and figure it out ... maybe it had curse words in it, or it had an attachment that the filter didn't like. You could try contacting the recipient and asking them what their mail filter system looks for as contraband and then look at the message you sent to see if you can figure out why it got flagged. Then remove whatever that is and re-send it.